# Placing a view without position absolute in react native

Tags: css, react-native, jsx

I am building this application, the issue with the layout is that it was built for browsers (HTML) in the first place and what I am doing now is converting the code to JSX. On the screenshot below you can see that I am trying to place the scrollable area next to the green image.

```
<div class="image-link">
<img src="images/green-link01.png" srcset="images/green-link01-2x.png" 
alt="image description" width="713" height="1084" usemap="#green- 
link01">
<map name="green-link01">
<area target="" alt="" title="" href="#" 
coords="7,1,1422,3,1423,742,432,744,430,2164,-1,2160" shape="poly">
</map>
```

[image: ss]

The result looks good on this screen size but on another devices it just don't render the same thing, obviously the damn white container width change, I set the width to 90%. If i use a fixed width it will become either too large or too small depending on the screen size.

I did try to come up with some creative ideas like splitting/cropping this green image to three different parts (images) that I'll put inside the views.

[image: ss]

```
    <View style={styles.floorHolder}>
        <View style={styles.containerBox}>
            <Image 
                source={require("../assets/green-link01-2x.png")}
                style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%", resizeMode: "contain", backgroundColor: 'white' }}
            />

            <ScrollView
                style={{
                    width: "67%",
                    height: "46%",
                    position: "absolute",
                    top: "40%",
                    bottom: '0%',
                    left: "33%",
                    right: '0%',
                    backgroundColor: "#f3ebd5",
                }}
            >
                    <Text>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
                    enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
                    nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
                    nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
                    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </Text>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    </View>
```

Not sure if this is the best solution, any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that should be the main solution if you want to have an adaptative view depending on the device screen size. I would suggest usgin flex (if you want the size to adapt to the screen)

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
  <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection: 'row'}}>
   <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'green'}}/>
   <View style={{flex:2,backgroundColor:'green'}}/>
  </View>
  <View style={{flex:2,backgroundColor:'green',flexDirection: 'row'}}>
   <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'green'}}/>
   <View style={{flex:2,backgroundColor:'gray'}}/>
  </View>
</View>
```

Ups... i missunderstood the question... i think you can use the aspectratio property for this one. you can give it a percentage with, a height of null and and aspectratio of 1 in this example, it should render an square. However i still recommend using width null, and flex:1/3 or flex 1/4 . IDK, experiment with it. I don't know if this example below works , it's the first thing that comes in my mind.

```
 <View style={styles.floorHolder}>
        <View style={styles.containerBox}>
            <Image 
                source={require("../assets/green-link01-2x.png")}
                style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%", resizeMode: "contain", backgroundColor: 'white' }}
            />

            <ScrollView
                style={{
                    width: "67%",
                    height: null,
                    position: "absolute",
                    left: "0",
                    right: '0',
                    backgroundColor: "#f3ebd5",
                    aspectRatio: 1
                }}
            >
                    <Text>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
                    enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
                    nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
                    nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
                    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </Text>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width)  Dimensions in RN are unitless, and represent density-independent pixels.  It should look like this.

```
      <Image 
        source={require("../assets/green-link01-2x.png")}
        style={{ height: 100, width: 100, resizeMode: "contain", backgroundColor: 'white' }}
        />

        <ScrollView
            style={{
                width: 67,
                height: 46,
                position: "absolute",
                top: 40,
                bottom: 0,
                left: 33,
                right: 0,
                backgroundColor: "#f3ebd5",
            }}
        >
```